# Validate email with javascript

Tags: javascript

I edited an existing validated function (included in a WordPress plugin) to add email validation feature.

```
function validateForm(form){
    var $ = jQuery;

// The code snippet I added
// **********************************
var emailID = document.getElementsByName('useremail')[0].value;
    atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
    dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

   if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
    {
        alert("Please enter correct email ID")
        return false;
    }

// End of the code added by me

else if(!$('input[name=title]', form).val()){
     alert("Please enter correct Name")
    $('input[name=title]', form).focus();
    return false;
    }
// ...
return true;
}
```

The html code:

```
<input type="text" name="useremail" id="useremail" required>
```

The email validation code was derived from [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript).

I think the part `var emailID = document.getElementsByName('useremail')[0].value;` is not correct.

I tried also to use `var emailID = document.getElementById('useremail');` which also does not work.

---

Added: `var emailID = document.getElementById('useremail');` should work. The problem was that the js file was not properly enqueued in WordPress. Thanks for all comments.

Comment: You think? Do a `console.log(emailID)`, is it what you expect it to be? Also note for the `id` it would be: `document.getElementById('useremail').value`.

Comment: `String.match()` or `RegExp.test()`.

Comment: Try using `var email = document.querySelector('#useremail').value`

Comment: why not use regular expression?

Comment: he can't even get the value from the input to use in a regexp if I understand his question.  But yes, I was wondering why not use the regexp too rather than all the positional checks.

Comment: Your `var` declarations are incorrect. You need commas between the individual variables, and just one semicolon at the end of the statement.'

Comment: that wouldn't be causing the issue would it?  Although he's declaring global vars it should still work no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works correctly in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adriel_santos/2rtya7pz/3/

Keep in mind that HTML5 has an input type that holds email:

```
 <input type="email" name="useremail" id="useremail" required>
```

Comment: Note that you use  `var emailID = $('#useremail').val();` instead of `var emailID = document.getElementsByName('useremail')[0].value;` (I'm assuming by your code that you have loaded the jquery library)